# Script editor make my team site go blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

Hello I am trying to add custom CSS code into script editor however when I do this into my team site page. the page goes blank. I would like to know what is reason for this happening. [image]

[image]

Comment: What DOM elements do you target in your CSS, and what does ``display:none`` do?

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman  it hide O365 menu bar and user personal settings

Comment: And what does it do without ``display:none`` ?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman it shows O365 menu bar. the page never when blank before it 1st time  i am experiencing it .